# Python PhantomJS, i can not enter a number

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

I want to send a number to the site. But you can not do this because the program hangs. Code:

```
input_code_user = input('Input code and press Enter:')
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@my-i18n='login_number_input_placeholder']")).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ng-model='credentials.phone_code']")).send_keys(input_code_user)
```

When the site is loaded, the code entry field looks like this:
[image: When the site is loaded, the code entry field looks like this:]

The code for this form looks like this:
[image: The code for this form looks like this:]
If you click on this field, it will look like this:
[image: If you click on this field, it will look like this:]
At the same place where the code was previously, it is replaced with a new one:
[image: Code2]
The program hangs on this code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ng-model='credentials.phone_code']")).send_keys(input_code_user)
```

I'm trying to take a screenshot after this line of code, but it is not created. The program works, but nothing happens. Help me find a solution.

Comment: Remove webDriverWait and use normal code split into two lines. One for find_element_by_xpath and one for send_keys. Then see which line is actually hanging